# Unable to start service with nohup due to 'INFO spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'app_name': EACCES'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, supervisord, nohup

I'm trying to start a service with supervisor, but I get an error saying

> INFO spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'app_name': EACCES

Here's my supervisord.conf file:

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB   ; change these depending on how many logs
logfile_backups=10      ; you want to keep
loglevel=info
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=true
minfds=1024
minprocs=200

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock  socket

[program:myscript]
command= python -u /home/ubuntu/appfolder/app_name.py
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected 
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/app_name.log
```

Comment: Seems like you have permission issues. Verify that the owner of the log file and app_name.py match the user that your program is executed with.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue - the celery sub program logs were being written in the logs subfolder under my app folder and turns out I had set the owner to `www-user` while I was debugging an issue with Nginx. I changed the owner of the app folder back to ubuntu (`>> whoami`)

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/myapp/
```

to get it to work.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is the permission for the log file
With the user running supervisor you can create a "logs" folder in the same path of the supervisord.conf file and change:

```
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
```

to

```
logfile=logs/supervisord.log
```

Comment: Same issue here, however I had already redirected the logs. A simple `touch logs/supervisord.log` showed that, for whatever reason, I didn't have write permissions for that directory. Adding write permissions fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

I get this error when running `supervisord` in an unprivileged [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) container, when I attempt to have `supervisord` run as a non-root user, using the `[supervisord]` `[user]` directive.

This caused by [docker #31243](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31243#issuecomment-406825071) where the container is started as `root` then another user is created/switched-to (as per `supervisord` changing to non-root) and the restrictive permissions on the container's `stdin/stdout/stderr` via it's TTY.

My workaround is to add the non-root user to the `tty` group e.g. `useradd -G tty supervisord`, making-sure that you run with a tty e.g. `docker run ... -t` or Docker Compose `tty: true`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I recommend doing the following

1. Add user who runs the service.
   user=youruser
2. moving your log to a supervisor dir

from:

```
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
```

to:

```
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
```

The same goes to you pid file

```
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid >> pidfile=/var/run/supervisor/supervisord.pid
```

Make both dirs

```
mkdir /var/run/supervisor/

mkdir /var/log/supervisor/
```

then change the of the dir with

```
chown youuser:youuser -R /var/log/supervisor/
```

If this dosen't work double check who can write on you log files and pid files.

```
ls -l /var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
```

If it still dosen't work try updating you supervisor

Answer (score 0):

the error info indicate your app "app_name" may read or write a file which has no privileges.

has you started supervisord with root, then switched to a specific user? in this case, you may create file in your "app_name" with owner of root, but the specific user may not have the right privileges.