# configure supervisor on amazon ec2 giving spawn error unknown error making dispatchers for 'app_name': EACCES

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, supervisord

I've seen this post [Unable to start service with nohup due to 'INFO spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'app_name': EACCES'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273197/unable-to-start-service-with-nohup-due-to-info-spawnerr-unknown-error-making-d) and tried the answer but it doesn't work

I'm using the Amazon AMI, and since Amazon doesn't have apt-get, I had to use easy_install to install supervisor. here is my /etc/supervisord.conf

```
[program:awesome]

command     = /srv/awesome/www/app.py
directory   = /srv/awesome/www
user        = ec2-user
startsecs   = 3

redirect_stderr         = true
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 50MB
stdout_logfile_backups  = 10
stdout_logfile          = /srv/awesome/log/app.log
```

my app files are placed under /srv/awesome/www/ and the owner set to ec2-user which is the same user when I ran whoami. I first ran

```
supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

which gave me

> Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use.  Shut this program down first before starting supervisord.

I entered the command

```
sudo unlink /tmp/supervisor.sock
```

which resolved it, then I did

```
supervisorctl start awesome
```

which spawn the error, I've tried reloading, stop and start but none works

Comment: Which port is your "magic" app.py running on?

Comment: 9000, I changed to ubuntu server and everything worked out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to ubuntu instead of amazon AMI and everything worked out